# word automation script only checking some of the checkboxes

Tags: python, ms-word, automation, ironpython

I wrote an IronPython script to check all the checkboxes in a Word document.  However it only checks **some of them**!

`input.docx` is a Word document that contains many checkboxes, all unchecked.
If I run the script, `output.docx` contains the same content as `input.docx` except with **some** of the checkboxes checked.  My intent is for **all** of them to be checked.

What could be wrong with my script?

```
# Add the reference for Word
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word")
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word as Word

# Start Word
word_application = Word.ApplicationClass()
word_application.visible = False

# Open the input file
document = word_application.Documents.Open(r"c:\tst\input.docx")

# Check all the checkboxes
for ctrl in document.ContentControls:
    ctrl.Checked = True

# Save and close the output file
document.SaveAs(r"c:\tst\output.docx")
document.Close()

# Quit Word
word_application.Quit()
```